# How to check version of iOS Branch SDK

Tags: ios, branch.io

I am working on a project which uses Branch iOS SDK for app referral & deep linking. Previous developers were already installed Branch SDK by adding it manually to the project. Now I am getting method not found error when I use

```
- (BOOL)continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity;
```

method to support iOS 9 universal deep linking. My assumption is that the error is occurring because of old Branch SDK which doesn't support universal deep linking. Now I want to know how to check version of Branch SDK using in the project, so that I can check whether it support universal deep linking or not ?

Comment: What do you mean by **adding it manually**? Did they use `Carthage` or `CocoaPods` or anything else?

Comment: @p They didn't use `CocoaPods` or `Carthage`. They have added Branch SDK by dragging `Branch.framework ` file in to the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex from Branch.io here:

You can check the version number in the **Info.plist** file inside the framework package. Look for these lines:

```
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>{version number}</string>
```

Universal Links have been supported [since v0.11](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/ios-branch-deep-linking/blob/c8cb719de202870ec65d2cc7d0a696c62d090cee/ChangeLog.md). However, even if you have a version with support, you really should be using the latest version at all times since we're constantly adding new functionality and handling for edge cases from Apple and others (there was a new one just this week with iOS 10.2, for example)

Comment: How to know the minmum iOS version that the Branch SDK supports, since my project supports iOS 6, just wanted to confirm whether the latest Branch SDK release (v0.12.2) can be used for iOS 6?

Comment: We no longer test the SDK against iOS 6, since it's at ~0.5% market share these days. It's possible that v0.12.2 still works, but the lowest we can guarantee is iOS 7. If you give it a try, please report back and let everyone know!